# Extracting text from PDF and transposing to Excel?

Tags: python, pypdf

So I have a large PDF document that holds lots of requirements and information points. One of my tasks is to extract the Requirement number and associated requirement. The document is structured as below:

R(1)   This is requirement 1
R(2)   This is requirement 2
I(1)   This is information point 1

Etc.

I'd like to be able to extract the Requirement number in one excel column and associated text with said requirement in another excel column from the PDF and put into a structured table. I'm unsure whether there's any libraries on Python that can do this (PyPDF2?) or if it'll require some SQL work as well.

I'm very new to Python/SQL but willing to give it a go.

The document also has lots of headers in it which would be great if I could extract, but I can always add these manually.

Thanks in advance all. Apologies if its a big ask.

Honestly not tried anything yet - not applied Python in a real scenario yet

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. As stated in the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) this site is about answering specific coding issues. I suggest you read about tools that might help solve your problem first. I recently came across a [tutorial](https://realpython.com/creating-modifying-pdf/), about working with python on pdfs. That might be a good start for you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: use `pypdf`, `PyPDF2` will be deprecated

Comment: PyPDF2 is already deprecated. I am the maintainer of both and I will not add any new features to PyPDF2. We will also only add security fixes + only if they are supplied by a good PR that can easily be merged. As pypdf is a superset of PyPDF2, **there is absolutely no reason to still use PyPDF2**